# BigQuery ML outputs different regression coefficients from Sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, google-bigquery, linear-regression

I am running a ridge regression model in BigQuery ML, and i am comparing it against the same model with same parameters trained in python using sklearn. Even though they share the same parameters and training data, the coefficients are not the same between the two.

This is what the model training using bigquery ML looks like:

```
CREATE MODEL
  `mydataset.ridgemodel`
OPTIONS
  ( MODEL_TYPE='LINEAR_REG',
    L2_REG=10,
    FIT_INTERCEPT = 'true',
    HPARAM_TUNING_OBJECTIVES = ['mean_squared_error']
     ) AS
SELECT
  *
FROM
  model_df
```

This is what the model training using Sklearn looks like:

```
model = Ridge(alpha = 10) 
model.fit(X, y)     # X,y come from model_df as above
```

These two models are trained on the same data with the same parameters but still yield coefficients that are slightly different from one another. I also ran the models by specifying 'normal equation' as optimizer for both, but still got different results. Maybe the two models use different loss functions underneath?

What could be leading to non-identical results from these two models?

Comment: I have translated some models from stat package to another, and the coefficients are always not the same. Sometimes you can make them equal to the third digit reading through all the model parameters in the documentation and aligning the models, but still the results are not always 100% the same due to different implementations of algorithms or due to some random values involved in the model calculations that one cannot control.